# Sort array with characters in Javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting, ecmascript-6

I am sorting an array with numeric values and "-" as a characters.
My array is

```
var arr = [5, 3, 10, "-", 2, "-"]
```

I want this to sort with numeric values followed by all the "-" characters.

Required result:-

```
final array = [10, 5, 3, 2, "-", "-"]
```

What i have tried:-

```
var array_with_chars= arr.filter(function( element ) {
    return element.name == '-';
});
var array_with_nums= arr_obj.filter(function( element ) {
    return element.name !== '-';
});

array_with_nums.sort(function(a, b) {
  return b.name - a.name;
});

for(var i = 0; i< array_with_chars.length; i++){
    array_with_nums.push(array_with_chars[i])
}
```

Is there any good way to sort this in single iteration?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "special" characters? And how do you want the special ones ordered? Thx.

Comment: I have only "-" as a character which need to come in last.

Comment: If "-" is the only non-numerical character then you can just do `arr.sort(function(a,b) { return b - a });`

Comment: wrong dupe target, because it does not answer the question of not a number items for sorting.

Comment: @NinaScholz: Then change the target to a proper one. I'm sure it exists.

Comment: @Cerbrus these dupe questions you provided don't include characters, they're only about integers.

Comment: @TahaPaksu: I've added another target a minute ago. This question is a duplicate of so many others.

Comment: @Cerbrus ok that looks fair enough.

Answer (score 2):

You could check for `NaN` and move this items to the end.

```js
var array = [5, 3, 10, "-", 2, "-"];

array.sort((a, b) => isNaN(a) - isNaN(b) || b - a);

console.log(array);
```

Comment: It works--

var array = [5, 3, 10, "-", 2, "-"];

array.sort((a, b) => isNaN(a) - isNaN(b) || b - a);

Thanks @Nina

Comment: Nice. One of those cases in which arithmetic-on-booleans-as-integers work pretty well.

Comment: So, instead of closing obvious duplicates, you're ___still___ answering them.